# $.get(u,d,c,"JSON") vs $.getJSON(u,d,c)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, get, getjson

I generally use `$.get()` and `$.post()` for all of my asynchornous calls, but they're usually qualified with the final parameter being "JSON," indicating that I'm expecting to handle JSON data within my callback.

Is there any benefit to using `$.get([url],[data],[callback],"JSON")` over `$.getJSON([url],[data],[callback])`? Is it nothing more than no longer needing to include the final parameter, an explicit declaration of the return type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No difference. It's obvious from the [jQuery source](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/src/ajax.js). I use `getJSON` for all cross domain calls and `get` when calls follow same origin policy.

```
getJSON: function( url, data, callback ) {
  return jQuery.get(url, data, callback, "json");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. And thank you also for introducing me to this much more exhaustive and detailed presentation of the jQuery source.

Answer (score 2):

As @Chandra pointed out, it is a convenience method. I checked the source as well to be sure, and it simply calls `$.get`. So, the only performance of `$.get` over `$.getJSON` is there would be one less method call. However, since it seems to be clearer, I would say that using `$.getJSON` should be preferred over `$.get`

Comment: +1 I'm a man of brevity - I suppose that is why I preferred `$.get()` over and against `$.getJSON()`, but I agree that from a clearer and more readable perspective, `$.getJSON()` makes more sense when you're "getting JSON." Thanks, Doug!

Comment: What gets me is everyone using `$.ajax("GET"...` requests. `$.get` and `$.post` is just way more clear and easy to write. Glad I could help!

Comment: Since the "json" generally comes after an inline function declaration, the formatting is a little funky and it can get lost. I like how getJSON saves you from having that extra argument after the function.